# Passport - user is not stored in session

Tags: node.js, session, express, passport.js

I am new to `nodejs` so I was trying to make an authentication system. I implemented it after following a tutorial.
In order to fetch the user object when authenticated, you need to store it in session. I did so by configuring `express-session` as follows:

```
require('./config/passport')(passport); // pass passport for configuration

app.use(session({
    secret: 'thisisagreatgreatsecretforthesession',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));

app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended : false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(flash());

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.locals.user = req.user;
  next();
});


var routes = require('./app/routes')(app, passport);
```

and then in passport I configured the serialize and deserialize functions as follows:

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
        done(null, user.id);
    });

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
        User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
            done(err, user);
        });
    });
```

I tried to console the user in the `deserializeUser` function and it was correct. However when I called `user` in the template, I got an error stating user is not defined.

Am I missing something else in the configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Session properties aren't exposed to templates by default.

If you want to access `req.user` from your templates, you can use a simple Express middleware that will expose it:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.locals.user = req.user;
  next();
});
```

(make sure that this middleware is added *after* the `session` and Passport middlewares, but *before* any routes that render templates that access `user`; with Express, the order in which you declare middleware matters)

This uses [`res.locals`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.locals) as a way to expose data to all templates. In fact, if you look at the Express documentation, it almost shows the exact same code as an example of how to expose the user data.

Comment: I am not getting any errors now but still nothing is displayed in the template when I use `user`. Is the order of the configuration correct so far?

Comment: If you're not getting any errors, the template can access `user`. You can add `console.log(req.user)` inside the middleware to make sure that it actually has a value (it's most likely an object, from which you have to use properties in your template, like `user.username` or something like that).

Comment: `console.log(req.user)` works fine but in the template when I use `<% user.name %>`, I get nothing at all

Comment: @omarsafwany assuming you're using EJS templates, that should proably be `<%= user.name %>`